# Oracle query: Can it be more efficient?

Tags: performance, oracle

I am having issues in that the below query is causing some timeout issues when a date range longer than 30 years is selected.

Can the below be made more efficient?

```
select TB_INJECTIONANDPRODUCTION.STANDARDOILFIELD, 
TB_INJECTIONANDPRODUCTION.WELLNAME, 
to_char(TB_INJECTIONANDPRODUCTION.MEASUREMENTDATE,'YYYY'), 
sum(TB_INJECTIONANDPRODUCTION.MONTHLYOILPRODUCTION), 
sum(TB_INJECTIONANDPRODUCTION.MONTHLYGASPRODUCTION), 
sum(TB_INJECTIONANDPRODUCTION.CONDENSATE), 
sum(TB_INJECTIONANDPRODUCTION.FREEGAS), 
sum(TB_INJECTIONANDPRODUCTION.MONTHLYWATERPRODUCTION), 
sum(TB_INJECTIONANDPRODUCTION.MONTHLYWATERINJECTION) 
from TB_INJECTIONANDPRODUCTION 
where 
TB_INJECTIONANDPRODUCTION.ENTITLEMENT like 'AZNEFT_28May%' and 
TB_INJECTIONANDPRODUCTION.STANDARDOILFIELD = ? and 
TB_INJECTIONANDPRODUCTION.WELLNAME = ? and 
to_char(TB_INJECTIONANDPRODUCTION.MEASUREMENTDATE,'YYYY') >= ? and 
to_char(TB_INJECTIONANDPRODUCTION.MEASUREMENTDATE,'YYYY') <= ?
group by 
TB_INJECTIONANDPRODUCTION.STANDARDOILFIELD, 
TB_INJECTIONANDPRODUCTION.WELLNAME, 
to_char(TB_INJECTIONANDPRODUCTION.MEASUREMENTDATE,'YYYY')
order by 
TB_INJECTIONANDPRODUCTION.STANDARDOILFIELD, 
TB_INJECTIONANDPRODUCTION.WELLNAME, 
to_char(TB_INJECTIONANDPRODUCTION.MEASUREMENTDATE,'YYYY')
```

Thank you all very much.

Comment: Do you have the right columns indexed?

Comment: You need to put some more info on your question for an appropriated answer. Like The amount of data on your table and the explain plan of your query. Also the version of oracle that you are running this will also be good.

Comment: Yes Arminin, there are indexer jobs which run on these fields as part of an overnight routine.   Am I asking the server to process too much with the way I am entering the date criteria etc?

Comment: the answer is: not enough info.  But why would you do a to_char on the date (forcing Oracle to convert every date so it can compare)?  Try passing actual dates for measurement_date bind values.

Comment: Does the execution plan change for small and large ranges of years?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you some things that you can do on your query.

First of all use [EXTRACT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm) instead of TO_CHAR as it is faster for date extract.

```
to_char(TB_INJECTIONANDPRODUCTION.MEASUREMENTDATE,'YYYY')
```

To

```
extract(YEAR From TB_INJECTIONANDPRODUCTION.MEASUREMENTDATE)
```

Avoid this type of operation

```
to_char(TB_INJECTIONANDPRODUCTION.MEASUREMENTDATE,'YYYY') >= ?
```

It most likely doing an **implicit conversion** (which is very bad for performance). I'm assuming that you are passing a number to this parameter. So use extract again here to.

See the other parameter types and the database field types to avoid implicit conversion. E.g. if the TB_INJECTIONANDPRODUCTION.STANDARDOILFIELD is a number pass the parameter as a number.

Use the `between` to avoid two calling for the extract function:

```
to_char(TB_INJECTIONANDPRODUCTION.MEASUREMENTDATE,'YYYY') >= ? and 
to_char(TB_INJECTIONANDPRODUCTION.MEASUREMENTDATE,'YYYY') <= ?
```

To this:

```
extract(year from TB_INJECTIONANDPRODUCTION.MEASUREMENTDATE) between ? and ?
```

This is just suggestions. Without more info on your question that is all I can suggest.